# Bloodborne hunters fighting in central yharnam

Tags: bloodborne

In my game, I spawned at the central Yharnam light post a while after defeating  ‎Father Gascoigne, but before defeating the blood starved beast. One dropped the crow hunters badge, while the other one dropped the "heir" rune.

I know the one that dropped the badge is a hunter with a quest line, but I can't remember which one. (I have been reading the play through because I'm still learning how to play well.)

I am just curious if this is a normal thing, or something that wasn't normally supposed to happen. And furthermore, will this affect my game later on?

Answer (score 8):

This is a story event. This particular fight is tricky, because you are meant to aid one of them (Eileen) in killing the other (Henryk), but without aggro-ing her either.

This particular event triggers after talking with [Eileen The Crow](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Eileen+the+Crow) in the Cathedral Ward, and then opening the shortcut to the Grand Cathedral.

In this fight, she will be attempting to kill [Henryk](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Henryk) (Later found out to be Gascoigne's partner in the Hunt). If you let this play out without intervening, there is a very small chance Eileen will survive (Eileen surviving is the intended outcome). So you are meant to step in and help. The problem is that if you deal too much damage to Eileen, she will aggro on you as well.

Answer (score 4):

To further [Ben's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/324624/33618). The quest line for [Eileene The Crow](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/raven-hunter.html) ended in her death and thus failure. You missed a few gestures she can teach you and another fight with an [NPC hunter](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/08/bloody-crow-of-cainhurst.html). As well as the satisfaction of her being alive and well at the end of your Hunt.

However, you have the [Crow Hunter Badge](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/crow-hunter-badge.html) early which allows you to buy her [attire](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/crowfeather-set.html) and [weapon](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/warped-twinblades.html) with blood echoes. The latter has superb skill scaling and very good arcane scaling but requires user skill to use.

Comment: "User Skill" - is that referring to the Stat, or the Player ability?

Comment: @Ben It has super skill stat scaling. It requires user skill to use at its full potential -- R1 spamming is nice but not the most effective attack chain. Although, it does stun lock many enemies.